# Firefox change taskbar and desktop icons

Tags: firefox

I use to be able to change firefox icons by adding these files to the Firefox under the browser directory

```
chrome/icons/default/BrowserPreferences.ico
chrome/icons/default/CustomizeToolbarWindow.ico
chrome/icons/default/default.ico
chrome/icons/default/downloadManager.ico
chrome/icons/default/main-window.ico
chrome/icons/default/openLocation.ico
chrome/icons/default/places.ico
chrome/icons/default/printPageSetupDialog.ico
chrome/icons/default/TabMIxPreferences.ico
chrome/icons/default/unknownContentType.ico
chrome/icons/default/viewSource.ico
chrome/icons/default/Wizard.ico
```

It worked in version 56 but now in version 97 and this no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

After version it now needs an option in prefs.js

```
user_pref("toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.windowIcon", true);
```

to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by changing the icon in the .exe file. It can be tedious and that's why I have put it into a shell script. You need to install [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) first and nice way to do that is by using the Scoop package manager:

```
scoop install resource-hacker
```

To change an icon, I use the following code (variables are specifically for my use case):

```
$exe = "$env:ProgramFiles\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"
$ico = "$env:HomePath\.config\firefox\firefox-classic.ico"

cp "$exe" "$exe.bak"
resourcehacker.exe -open $exe -save "$exe.tmp" -action addoverwrite -resource $ico -mask "ICONGROUP,1,"
resourcehacker.exe -open "$exe.tmp" -save $exe -action addoverwrite -resource $ico -mask "ICONGROUP,32512,"
```

Resource Hacker has an excellent GUI, but I prefer to use this method for quick access. An informative article on this topic is available at [How to get the old Firefox icon](https://geekswipe.net/curiosity/topic/how-to-get-the-old-firefox-icon/).